# How to update python SQLite rows while iterating through a table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm a newbie at SQLite for python and I'm confused about how to update a row while iterating through a table.

Here is some sample code:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

points = [
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9),
    (10,11,12)
]

point_data = lite.connect('points.db')
cur = point_data.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS points")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE points(x1,y1,z1)")
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO points VALUES(?, ?, ?)", points)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM points")

while True:
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row == None:
        break
    row_sum = row[0]+row[1]+row[2]
```

I would like to know how to insert the `row_sum` as the fourth column using an `UPDATE` command. Do I have to define the fourth 'column' when I define the table?

Comment: Yes. You can also add column later with a query, but if you are sure you need 4 columns, just define all columns when you create the table.
I'm not sure if i understand your question... it's so strange..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you wouldn't do that in Python.

SQL databases have a fixed structure, you would need to create a total column in the CREATE TABLE statement, or add it via an UPDATE TABLE... ADD COLUMN statement.

But then, instead of SELECT followed by UPDATE, you could just do a single UPDATE:

```
UPDATE points SET total = (x1 + y1 + z1);
```

Note however that you might not actually need to store the total in the db at all: you could just calculate it dynamically in exactly the same way when you do the SELECT:

```
SELECT x1, y1, z1, x1+y1+z1 as total FROM points;
```

Comment: thanks for this. if the column were already defined, how can I update just one element of that row? i don't want to update all rows. is there a built-in row ID that I can use?

Comment: No, you should define a primary key column for that (and then add `WHERE id = my_id_number` to the update statement). To be honest, this is all really basic SQL stuff (and nothing to do with Python at all): you should go and do an introductory SQL tutorial.